# Can you select an element via CSS with more classes with a same name?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I was just wondering if you can select an element, which has multiple classes with same name, e.g. `<p class="demo test demo">` with CSS selector `.demo.demo`?

Example code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .demo {    
        color: blue;
      }
      .demo.demo {    
        color: red;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p class="demo">This should be blue</p>
    <p class="demo demo">This should be red</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

In this example the `.demo.demo` selector overrides the `.demo` selector. Why is that, and is this even possible to do **in CSS**?

Comment: CSS: `Cascading` Style Sheets

Comment: `.demo.demo` should work even without duplicating the classes in html. or more precisely, you can cascade the same class any times you want like `.demo.demo.demo.demo`. It just increases the specificity level.

Comment: `demo.demo` says "element who has the class `demo` and the class `demo` and that right to element with only one `demo` class.

Comment: even when you have a single class you can target it with the same classname chained, so `.demo.demo.demo... .demo` will also target an element with a single `.demo` class. Try to entirely remove the first rule

Comment: You might want to try `[class="demo demo"]`. or altogether change your approach.. seems you are going in wrong direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.demo.demo` means "It is member of the class *demo* and is a member of the class *demo*". It doesn't matter how many times `demo` appears in the class attribute, it is still a member of that class and each requirement that it be a member of that class will be matched.

`.demo.demo` overrides `.demo` because it is more specific. Even if that wasn't the case, it appears later in the stylesheet. See the [cascading order](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order) in the spec.

If you want to select an element where the same class name appears in the attribute value multiple times, then you are out of luck. [Attribute selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors) allow for some relatively complex rules, but none of them allow you to match two sets of content with arbitrary content between them.

If your particular example, you could do something like:

```
[class^=demo][class$=demo] {}
```

… i.e. begins *and* ends with demo, but that would also match `class="demo"`.

You could also do:

```
[class="demo demo"]
```

… but that wouldn't match `class="foo demo bar demo baz"`.

Comment: [Selectors 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity) contains an explicit statement that repetitions of the same class selector do increase specificity. This was not present in CSS2, a point of contention among vendors I believe.

Comment: As for matching elements with duplicate classes, this appears to be a limitation of CSS, since HTML doesn't seem to disallow specifying duplicate classes in the first place (<p class="demo demo"> validates in HTML 4 and HTML5). Perhaps at the time it was designed, the CSSWG assumed no one in their right mind was going to specify duplicate classes on elements.

Answer (score 0):

.demo.demo has more depth compared to single demo. So whenever only single class of demo is used in the `<p>` element it directly takes the .demo.demo class.
I tried even this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .yellow.yellow.yellow {
            color: yellow;
        }

            .demo.demo {
                color: blue;
            }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="demo yellow">This should be blue</p>
    <p class="demo demo">This should be red</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and the result was first `<p>` was yellow and second red.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `.demo.demo` selector, but you may do trick like `[class^="demo "][class$=" demo"]`.

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/jqfmkemx/)

This example only works if first `demo` is first class, and last `demo` is the last class. If this is not fit your actual case, I may provide some additional selectors, but I guess there is no *universal* selector for this.

Answer (score -2):

Normally browser will support only the first class property. if you select any multiple same class names it will affect or override the property value. once you added any extra element of the classes it will generate new class property.

so

```
.demo { color:red;}
.demo.demo {color:blue}
```

here both are same property value will return. if you create the new classes like

```
.demo.test.demo{color:blue}
```

it will affect a new class but the browser will select only new class property